# Pricing kernel representation

Tags: fixed-income, interest-rates, bond, asset-pricing, affine-processes

I am reading this paper https://mpra.ub.uni-muenchen.de/4969/1/MPRA_paper_4969.pdf pp.6-7 on discrete-time bond pricing. The model adopted  is a a common affine model,

the short rate follows
\begin{equation}
r_t = a + b' X_t
\end{equation}

the state variables $X_t$, under $Q$, follows
\begin{equation}
X_t = \bar{\mu} + \bar{\rho} X_{t-1} + \Sigma \eta_t
\end{equation}
so that the price at time $t$ of a bond paying a unitary amount at time $t+n$ equals
\begin{equation}
p_t^n = E_t^Q(\exp{(-r_t) p_{t+1}^{n-1})}
\end{equation}
According to the authors "The
link between the risk-neutral distribution Q and the historical distribution
P is given by the prices of risk, denoted by $\lambda_0 = \Sigma^{-1} (\mu-\bar{\mu})$ and $\lambda_1 = \Sigma^{-1} (\rho-\bar{\rho})$:

\begin{equation}
\frac{dQ}{dP}\vert_t = \frac{\xi_{t+1}}{E(\xi_{t+1})}
\end{equation}
with \begin{equation}
\xi_{t+1} = \prod_{j=1}^{\infty} \exp{((-\lambda_0 + \lambda_1 X_{t+j-1}) \epsilon_{t+j})}.
\end{equation}

However, I do not understand the representation of the pricing kernel: where this last product comes from?

Usually, for instance in [https://web.stanford.edu/~piazzesi/AP.pdf](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Epiazzesi/AP.pdf),
the pricing kernel is
\begin{equation}
M_{t,t+1}= \exp{(-r_t -\frac{1}{2} \lambda_t' \lambda_t - \lambda_t' \epsilon_t)}
\end{equation}
so that

\begin{equation}
E_t[M_{t,t+1}]= \exp{(-r_t)}
\end{equation}

And defining

\begin{equation}
\xi_{t,t+1}=\exp{(r_t M_{t,t+1}})=\exp{(-\frac{1}{2} \lambda_t' \lambda_t - \lambda_t'\epsilon_{t+1})}
\end{equation}

we can define a new measure $Q$ equivalent to $P$ since $E[\xi_{t,t+1}]=1$ and $\xi_{t,t+1}>0$, and clearly,$\frac{dQ}{dP}\vert_t = \xi_{t,t+1} $ is the Radon-Nikodym derivative

Are these two representation equivalent?

thank you very much

Comment: I think the notion is confusing though I have seen both forms before. Apparently the Radon-Nikodym derivative is defined over a random variable with arbitrary time horizons versus the latter definition concerns time $t+1$ variables. This is similar to arbitrary horizon vs period by period stochastic discount factors.